# Como configurar el CKeditor para que acepte etiquetas html

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, ckeditor

Tengo un inconvenitne al momento de configurar mi editor Ckeditor por que guarda las entiquetas html como la etiqueta `<p>` con estos entities =<p&gt , ya agregue la configuración entities **config.entities = false;** pero aun asi solo guarda los carecteres especiales (ó,ñ ect ),

esta es mi configuracion

```js
/**
 * @license Copyright (c) 2003-2012, CKSource - Frederico Knabben. All rights reserved.
 * For licensing, see LICENSE.html or http://ckeditor.com/license
 */

CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
 config.entities = false;
 // Define changes to default configuration here.
 // For the complete reference:
 // http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config

 // The toolbar groups arrangement, optimized for two toolbar rows.
 config.toolbarGroups = [
  { name: 'clipboard',   groups: [ 'clipboard', 'undo' ] },
  { name: 'editing',     groups: [ 'find', 'selection', 'spellchecker' ] },
  { name: 'links' },
  { name: 'insert' },
  { name: 'forms' },
  { name: 'tools' },
  { name: 'document',    groups: [ 'mode', 'document', 'doctools' ] },
  { name: 'others' },
  '/',
  { name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'cleanup' ] },
  { name: 'paragraph',   groups: [ 'list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align' ] },
  { name: 'styles' },
  { name: 'colors' },
  { name: 'about' }
 ];

 // Remove some buttons, provided by the standard plugins, which we don't
 // need to have in the Standard(s) toolbar.
 config.removeButtons = 'Underline,Subscript,Superscript';
};
```

gracias por cualquier sugerencia para que me acepte las etiquetas html

Comment: Hola Edison, no agregues tu código como una imagen sino que es mejor que lo pongas como texto (o en este caso como un snippet). Lee sobre cómo crear un [mcve] para más información.

Comment: vale gracias , lo modificare